# search bar color is not exact in seacrhDisplayController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have search bar in my app and the problem is when I click to start typing the search bar change color. I wanted to set it programatically (via self.seacrhDisplayController.searchBar), but it is read only. Any idea how to set exact color? 
Thanks

[search bar in my view controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W24qP.png)

[search bar in search display controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/davau.png)

Comment: Can you be more specific, you want to change the color of the background ?

Comment: Yes, I added images so you can see the difference.

Answer (score 1):

This is done with

```
self.searchDisplayController?.searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.black
self.searchDisplayController?.searchBar.isTranslucent = false
```

If you're creating it with Storyboard, first make sure

- **SearchDisplayController** *referencing outlet* is set to **file owner**
- **Search Bar** *referencing outlet* is set to the **Search Display Controller**

**EDIT** - Added image and alpha solution

Need to remove the background image or set a background image that has your desired color.

[image]

`self.searchDisplayController?.searchBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()`
or 
`self.searchDisplayController?.searchBar.backgroundImage = UIImage(named: "search_background")`

**Note**:
If you want to get rid of the deprecated warning you have to create a UISearchController instead, this is not available with Storyboard

[Useful UISearchController tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/113772/uisearchcontroller-tutorial)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but it didn´t solve the problem the color is still lighter in search display controller.

Comment: Problem is there's a background image with alpha... You can do
`self.searchDisplayController?.searchBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()`
Or set background image to one that has your desired color

Comment: You can set `backgroundImage` to `UIImage()` and then change `backgroundColor` to desired one

Comment: I tried it, but it still did not solved my problem. I do not know why but backgroundColor changes search bar color just in my view controller, bar tint color changes color in search display controller